# What rates does CME use for the SOFR futures settlement prices

Tags: sofr, cme

I am reading CME Methodology for SOFR Future settlement calculation. The calculation seems to be straight forward but I am confused about the data CME uses for settlement price.

I am assuming it is using average SOFR prices published by newyorkFed T+1.

I was following the example outlined in SOFR Futures Settlement Calculation. I couldn't find the same SOFR benchmark rates in Fed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the data in the document is fictional. It was built before futures traded. The [FED](https://www.newyorkfed.org/markets/reference-rates) published the first rate on April 3, 2018 (for April 2nd). The [CME note](https://www.cmegroup.com/education/articles-and-reports/sofr-futures-settlement-calculation-methodologies.html) also says its first trade date will be Monday, May 7, 2018.

Comment: Neither EFFR nor OBFR (in your screenshot) is [SOFR](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/SOFR). SOFR itself is identical to the settlement values from the [CME](https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/settlements.html) (look at the 3m SOFR future settlement file).

Comment: Might be fictional. Thank you